# Remove directory name from url? (example.org/folder1/file to example.org/file)

Tags: php, html, css

I'm looking to make a goo.gl/bit.ly etc type domain shortener for my private use using my domain. I've got the script set up to make a file etc, my only issue is that I want to have each new file be created into a new folder (redirects/file), but I want to be able to have mydomain.eu/file redirect straight to the file located in the redirects directory. It seems this would be done using the .htaccess file, but I can't get that working. If anybody could provide any advice, it'd be greatly appreciated.

(Also, if anyone could provide info on how I could automatically clear out the redirects folder say, every week, that'd be great. :D )

I'm running Apache on CentOS, if that's relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't give us much to go on. Can you provide examples of what you've tried so far, what problems you are facing, and what specific question you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ redirects/$1 [R=301,L]
```